# How to render multiple times to same template in a single function block

Tags: html, django

I want to render multiple times in each if statement to same template. But in the HTML template it's only taking the last rendered statement.

I passed the context in the form of dictionary in the return render statement.

## views.py

```
if not match :
            #messages.info(requests,'Invalid')
            return render(requests, 'validate/home1.html', {'title' : 'Invalid mail'})
        if not country_code:
            return render(requests, 'validate/home1.html', {'title3' : 'Enter correct country code'})

        if not pwd_match :
            return render(requests, 'validate/home1.html', {'title1' : 'Enter password again'}) 
        if not phone :
            return render(requests, 'validate/home1.html', {'title2' : 'Enter 10 digit number'})
```

## home1.html

```
<form id="waterform" method="post" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="formgroup" id="name-form">
        <label for="name">Country Code*</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
    </div>
    <div>
            <p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px">{{ title3 }}</p>   
    </div>
    <div class="formgroup" id="email-form">
        <label for="email">Your e-mail*</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required />
    </div>

    <div>
            <p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px">{{ title }}</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="formgroup" id="email-form">
        <label for="password">Your password*</label>
        <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" required />
    </div>
```

I want to display each condition (title, title1, title2) which satisfies the if blocks.

Comment: Move your conditions into template then..

Comment: in your case, you should render form and validate form. It gives more clear code control, because, form validation does in form class, you have to just render errors if exist.

Comment: good guildeline : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. It will put all the errors in one dictionary and when rendering, if the error doesn't exist, will just display an empty ''.

```
a=''
b=''
c='' 
d=''

if not match :
         a = 'invalid mail'

        if not country_code:
            b = 'Enter correct country code'

        if not pwd_match :
            c = 'Enter password again' 
        if not phone :
            d = 'entire ten digit number'
        errors = {'title':a, 'title1': b, 'title2': c, 'title3':d}

        return render(requests, 'validate/home1.html', errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution will stop in the first match.

You should make all the validations before rendering and send the errors to the view, then write all those conditions on the template side.